# Ternary operation in setter VS Classic If

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

Currently working on modifying big mapping classes and some new rules have appeared making me wonder what is the best option here.

Imagine a classic mapping function like so:

```
yyy.setType(xxx.getType);
yyy.setSomething(xxx.getSomethigElse);
yyy.setThisAsWell(xxx.getThatAsWell);
```

And I now have a condition to check, what would be better? (knowing that I won't have future similar condition checking to do):

```
final Boolean isRuleApplying = xxx.getRule == RULE;
yyy.setType(
   isRuleApplying ? RULE_STUFF : xxx.getType
);
yyy.setSomething(
   isRuleApplying ? RULE_STUFF_OTHER : xxx.getSomethigElse
);
yyy.setThisAsWell(
   isRuleApplying ? RULE_STUFF_AGAIN : xxx.getThatAsWell
);
```

Or is it better to use the old if else?

```
if (xxx.getRule == RULE) {
   yyy.setType(RULE_STUFF);
   yyy.setSomething(RULE_STUFF_OTHER);
   yyy.setThisAsWell(RULE_STUFF_AGAIN);
} else {
   yyy.setType(xxx.getType);
   yyy.setSomething(xxx.getSomethigElse);
   yyy.setThisAsWell(xxx.getThatAsWell);
}
```

I feel that using ternary operation make it less maintainable and adds more complexity (checks everytime). But I wanted to get some other opinions.

Note: I have a bunch of try..catch so using if means duplicating those try blocks or adding an if in every block which kind of kills readability.

Comment: Use whichever seems more readable to you.

Comment: it's a matter of preference, rather than rule. but why perform the check three times, if you can do the same in one comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no absolute answer to this question. It depends.

With the ternary operator, you immediately see:

- Three properties are always set to some value, and it's always the same properties, independent of the condition.
- You see the two alternative values close to one another, so for a reader it's easy to compare them.

But there are some (many?) developers who arent't used to that operator (is that their fault or ours?), so using it might force them to look up its meaning instead of immediately understanding the code (to me, having a LISP background, the ternary operator always was as least natural as the `if` statement).

And it's true, with the ternary operator, you end up with three conditionals instead of one (but you should ignore these minor performance effects unless you find out that it really hurts in your application).

On the other hand, with the `if` statement, you immediately see:

- It's just one condition that influences all properties.
- You see the properties combinations for the two situations close together.

And even Java beginners will understand your code.

So, it depends on:

- the Java fluency of your co-workers
- whether you want to stress the different values for the single properties or the value-sets for the three properties.

And of course, all this isn't very object-oriented. If code structure and budget allow, maybe you could come up with a solution using polymorphism instead of the conditionals.

Comment: Thanks for that more in-depth answer :)